# Azure Datawarehouse Materialized view causing an issue in Database project Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have created a database project using the target as Azure SQL Datawarehouse in Visual Studio 2019 by importing the database. When I click on build it throws me an error for Materialized views. Since this is already present in the Datawarehouse it should not create an issue while creating a dacpac file.

Can you let me know if anyone has faced similar issue?

Comment: Hey @RonDunn, is there a gap between the tooling and Synapse dedicated SQL pools?

Comment: Can you post the exact error for the Materialized View please?